# Combine/Merge three Tableau Sheets into one

Tags: tableau-api

I have a single data source that lists customer IDs, purchase dates, paid dates, and receipt dates as such below.  I created three sheets that list the count of customers by month by respective purchase/paid/receipt dates.  I would like to create a third sheet or dashboard, that combines the three sheets. Is there a way to combine/join/union/merge sheets into one sheet or dashboard?

Raw Data:

```
Customer    Purchase    Paid    Receipt_Date
1           1/1/2019    1/1/2019    2/1/2019
2           1/1/2019    2/1/2019    4/1/2019
3           4/1/2019    6/1/2019    4/1/2019
4           5/1/2019    6/1/2019    6/1/2019
```

Tableau Sheet 1 Table

```
Month   Purchase_Count
1/1/2019    2
4/1/2019    1
5/1/2019    1
```

Tableau Sheet 2 Table

```
Month   Paid_Count
1/1/2019    1
2/1/2019    1
6/1/2019    2
```

Tableau Sheet 3 Table

```
Month   Receipt_Count
2/1/2019    1
4/1/2019    2
6/1/2019    1
```

Desired Tableau Sheet 3 or Dashboard

```
Month   Purchase    Paid    Receipt
1/1/2019    2          1    0
2/1/2019    0          1    1
4/1/2019    1          0    2
5/1/2019    1          0    0
6/1/2019    0          2    1
```

Comment: There is no need to combine the sheets. Desired output can be directly created with the fields available to you. Extend any sheet by putting all the desire fields directly in the sheet.